# Lucene - get document ids from term

Tags: java, lucene

In Lucene 4.1, I see you can use DirectoryReader.docFreq() to get the number of documents in an index containing a given term.  Is there a way to actually get those documents?  Either the objects or id numbers would be fine.  I think AtomicReader.termDocsEnum() would be useful, but I'm not sure if I can use AtomicReader - I don't see how to create an AtomicReader instance on a given directory.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why not just search for it?

```
IndexSearcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(directoryReader);
TermQuery query = new TermQuery(new Term("field", "term"));
TopDocs topdocs = searcher.query(query, numberToReturn);
```

Comment: Thanks!  That worked like a charm.  For future reference, to get the doc id's out of topdocs:


    `int docId = topdocs.scoredocs[i].doc;`